# IIS Settings proper but getting ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on iis 10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm deploying my website in ASP.NET 4.0 and receiving the below error

**The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server**

I checked ISAPI and CGI restrictions in IIS manager but status is allowed. But still I'm getting the error. Can some one help?

[image]

Please dont mark it as duplicate. I can't find answers for similar issue

Comment: Tried with both classc and integrated manager pipeline mode

Answer (score 0):

Try to allow unspecified CGI modules and ISAPI modules.

Open the IIS administrative Manager tool, and open ‘ISAPI and CGI Restrictions’:

[image]

Right-click on the white background, and choose ‘Edit Feature Settings’:

[image]

Tick the relevant box: Allow unspecified CGI modules, Allow unspecified ISAPI modules:

[image]